# How to get specific cell value of table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

suppose i have a itextsharp table called tblMain
which is having 5 columns and 10 rows

```
PdfPTable tblMain= new PdfPTable(5);

cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("hello", fdefault));
tblMain.addCell(cell1);
cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("hello2", fdefault));
tblMain.addCell(cell2);
.
.
.
```

so here how can i get value of some particular cell?

Comment: These tables are meant for creation and addition to documents, not for reading. So while there surely is some way to read values from a `PdfPTable`, it is not there by design and could be changed in the next update without warning. If itext 5 wasn't at its end-of-life yet which makes updates beyond important security patches extremely unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

i found its solution,following is the code that reads text of a cell:

```
 var cellValue = Mytable.GetRow(2).GetCells()[1].Phrase[0].ToString();
```

here you will get 1st positioned cell value of 2nd row of table.
hope this will be helpful for you.